# Building URL parameters in Android

Tags: android, url, uri

Currently I am using Uri.Builder to build URLs, but the issue I'm running in to is that the Uri.Buidler will encode colons(":), which as far as I can tell from other posts on StackOverflow, are valid for URL Parameters. Obviously, I don't know too much about what's valid for URLs and not URIs.

Is there something else I should use to build URLs? Or, maybe I shouldn't be using colons to for URL parameters in API calls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use `java.net.URI` package to build my URLs. I used it in this fashion:

```
uri = new URI(scheme, null, host, port, path_and_service_name, null, null);
```

HTH.